# batch distribute files in a folder into some folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a source folder, named `m_all`, and destination folders are named as `m_1, m_2, m_3... m_8`.

I want to copy files in source folder into destination folders,

in such a way that 2 files to m_1, 3 files to m_2, 2 files to m_3, 3 files to m_4..

There is no pattern among these target files.

How can I do that?

Comment: if there's no pattern among these files then how do you know which file to be put in which subfolder?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I don't need to know which files are moved into which folder, I just want to evenly distribute them into 8 folders. So if the number of my files is 40, there are 5 files in each folder

Comment: What happens with left over files? or have you always got multiples of twenty?

Comment: @Compo ahh, I'm sorry, I want to copy files so nothing happens with leftover files. they are just copied to destination folders. And yes. I assumed the number of files is 20. but the number of files can change, I'll treat that if I get to know the solution. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will distribute files evenly between the folders and if there are any files remaining, they'll be copied to the last folder

The input folder will be received in `%1`. The number of folders is put in `%totalfolder%` variable. The folder names (`m_1`... `m_8`) will be split into 2 parts: prefix (`m_`) in `%folderprefix%` variable and the folder number which is counted in `!foldernum!` variable

```bat
@Echo off

If "%1"=="" (
    Echo Usage: %0 '^<base folder^>'
    Exit /b
)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Get number of files in the folder
For /f %%A in ('dir %1 ^| find "File(s)"') do set totalfiles=%%A

Rem Set your parameters here
Rem First part of your folder name
Set folderprefix=m_
Rem m_1 ... m_8 => 8 folders
Set totalfolder=8

Set /a files_per_folder=totalfiles/totalfolder

Set filenum=1
Set foldernum=1
For %%f in (%1\*) do (
    Move "%%f" "%folderprefix%!foldernum!\"
    
    Rem Move to next folder by increasing folder number "
    If !filenum! EQU %files_per_folder% (
        If !foldernum! LSS %totalfolder% (
            Set /a foldernum+=1
            Set filenum=0
        )
    )
    Set /a filenum+=1
)
```

The script basically maintain a count of files in each folder and if the folder is filled completely it will move to the next folder

Comment: I'm trying to understand and execute your code, but in the first part(getting number of files) where do I put the location of source folder? I assigned my source directory in variable 'dir', like set dir = "C:\...\m_all".

Comment: @W.Cointreau it works on the current folder so just `cd` into the needed folder and run. But I've modified the script so now you can put the source folder in the first parameter, or you can put it in a variable if you want

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but when I just `echo %totalfiles%` after getting number of files in the folder, it does not work. why does this happen?

Comment: I have no idea, because when I `echo %totalfiles%` while debugging it still displays the correct number of files in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example, *(I feel certain there'll be a cleverer way of doing this)*. It should copy the files using the pattern you gave, until there's none left to copy. *(that means, for instance, the last file could be the only one copied to m_3)*

```bat
@Echo Off

(Set SrcDir=C:\Users\Cointreau\Documents\m_all)

If /I Not "%CD%"=="%SrcDir%" PushD "%SrcDir%" 2>Nul||Exit/B 
If "%~f0" Equ "%SrcDir%" Exit/B
For /L %%A In (1,1,8) Do If Not Exist "m_%%A" Exit/B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('DIR/B/A-D-S') Do (Set/A "i+=1"
    If !i! LEq 2 (Copy "%%A" "m_1") Else (If !i! LEq 5 (Copy "%%A" "m_2") Else (
            If !i! LEq 7 (Copy "%%A" "m_3") Else (If !i! LEq 10 (
                    Copy "%%A" "m_4") Else (If !i! LEq 12 (Copy "%%A" "m_5"
                        ) Else (If !i! LEq 15 (Copy "%%A" "m_6") Else (
                            If !i! LEq 17 (Copy "%%A" "m_7") Else (
                                If !i! LEq 20 (Copy "%%A" "m_8"
                                    If !i! Equ 20 Set i=0)))))))))
```

There is no code included to cater for copying existing files, i.e overwrite.

Change the location between the parentheses on line 3 to suit your actual source directory path.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure source folder
    set "source=m_all"

    rem Initialize targets array
    set "targets=0"
    for %%a in ( 
        "m_1" "m_2" "m_3" "m_4" "m_5" "m_6" "m_7" "m_8" 
    ) do (
        set /a "targets+=1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
        for %%b in ("!targets!") do endlocal & set "target.%%~b=%%~a"
    )

    rem Determine the number of files to copy
    for /f %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d "%source%\*" ^| find /c /v ""
    ') do set "nFiles=%%a"

    rem Initialize progress variables
    set /a "copied=0", "toCopy=0", "target=1", "processedFiles=0"

    rem For each file in source
    for %%a in ("%source%\*") do (
        rem Enable delayed expansion on start of first loop
        if not "!!"=="" setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

        rem One more file is being processed
        set /a "processedFiles+=1"

        rem Determine if we need to reevaluate where to place the file
        if !toCopy! lss 1 (
            if !processedFiles! gtr !nFiles! (
                rem More files have been added to the folder, deal with it
                set /a "target=(processedFiles %% targets) + 1", "toCopy=1"

            ) else for /l %%t in (!target! 1 %targets%) do if !toCopy!==0 (
                rem We are still handling the expected set of files
                set /a "target=%%t", "toCopy=nFiles*target/targets-copied", "copied+=toCopy"
            )
        )

        rem Prepare variables to be accessed without delayed expansion
        for %%b in ("!target!") do for %%t in ("!target.%%~b!") do (
            setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
                rem DEBUG CODE - Remove echo prefix if the output is correct
                echo copy "%%~fa" "%%~ft"
            endlocal
        )

        rem One file processed in current target
        set /a "toCopy-=1"
    )
```